# Import library name using short name or alias name

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

I am a newbie to programming. And I am confused between two major import statements. Also, I would like to know any advantage one have over other.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler as sc
```

and

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc=StandardScaler()
```

Comment: There's no major difference in above two. Only difference is you had to write `StandardScaler` twice in later code. using an alias will help you not to write the big module names again and again.

Comment: Probably just a typo, but I assume you didn't mean to call `()` the `StandardScaler`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference in both the code lines. By giving alias(easy) name, you avoid typing complete module name again and again. Also when there are multiple modules and submodules this is very useful.

```
import module.submodule.subsubmodule as short_name
```

maybe you can try below

```
#1st method
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler as sc
```

or

```
#2nd method
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScalar
```

By using the 1st method you can refer StandardScalar module by only its alias name (sc)

By using the 2nd method you can refer the StandardScaler by both its long name and alias name sc.

Ex:

```
import datetime
dt = datetime

datetime.datetime.now()
dt.datetime.now()
```